# regex to match string value and replace all occurrences in golang

Tags: go

what would be the regex to match string

```
"{{media url=\"wysiwyg/Out_story.png\"}}
```

or

```
"{{skin url=\"wysiwyg/Out_story.png\"}}
```

in Golang

I need to replace every instance of these, there could be any number of them and replace it with

`https://img.abc.com/xyz/valueOfURL` from above

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you have?

Comment: This is what I had before I posted : ({{media url=.*?}})

Comment: So what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`({{(media|skin) url=\\"(.*)\\"}})` should do the job.

It also will allow you to get the type (media or skin) as a string in your code for further use if needed.

For example, this code:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "regexp"

func main() {

    re := regexp.MustCompile(`{{(media|skin) url=.*}}`)
    stringMedia := "{{media url=\"wysiwyg/Out_story.png\"}}"
    stringSkin := "{{skin url=\"wysiwyg/Out_story.png\"}}"

    match := re.FindStringSubmatch(stringMedia)
    if len(match) != 0 {
        fmt.Printf("1. %s\n", match[1])
    }

    match = re.FindStringSubmatch(stringSkin)
    if len(match) != 0 {
        fmt.Printf("2. %s\n", match[1])
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
1. media
2. skin
```

Then, to replace the match with the URL it contained, you can do something like this (Note the tweaks to the regexp to capture the full match as well as the url independently):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    re := regexp.MustCompile(`({{(media|skin) url=\\"(.*)\\"}})`)
    stringMedia := "other stuff {{media url=\"wysiwyg/Out_story.png\"}} other stuff"
    stringSkin := "other stuff {{skin url=\"wysiwyg/Out_story.png\"}} other stuff"

    match := re.FindStringSubmatch(stringMedia)
    if len(match) != 0 {
        stringMedia = strings.Replace(stringMedia, match[1], fmt.Sprintf("https://img.abc.com/xyz/%s", match[3]), -1)
        fmt.Println(stringMedia)
    }

    match = re.FindStringSubmatch(stringSkin)
    if len(match) != 0 {
        stringSkin = strings.Replace(stringSkin, match[1], fmt.Sprintf("https://img.abc.com/xyz/%s", match[3]), -1)
        fmt.Println(stringSkin)
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
other stuff https://img.abc.com/xyz/wysiwyg/Out_story.png other stuff
other stuff https://img.abc.com/xyz/wysiwyg/Out_story.png other stuff
```

You can test it out yourself on [regex-golang.appspot.com](https://regex-golang.appspot.com/assets/html/index.html) or on the [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Kj2EG4gqzyO).

Comment: Thanks. I needed to add ? after .* otherwise it took everything. What about replacing it with the appended value? I need to replace every instance of these, there could be any number of them and replace it with

https://img.abc.com/xyz/valueOfURL from ab

Comment: If it's from a string that you want to replace it, what you need is to use [strings.Replace](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace).

Comment: I'll update the answer with the whole thing

Comment: Thanks :)..........

Comment: The example I originally put also captured the double quotes, fixed it now it should do exactly what you want. For next time though, when asking a question here, please include at least a piece of code that you wrote as an attempt, and we'll guide you through making it work, rather than code it for you :p

Comment: Sure. The new code does not seem to be working though. https://play.golang.org/p/AfeoxBIa2Oy @Ullaakut